# Does Assets support categories?

Tags: assets

I'm looking to create a file repository of PDFs.

One way I was thinking to do this is to just use the native file manager with categories to sort the content.  But I would prefer to use Assets, but I can't find anywhere mentioning if it supports categories or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to organize it at the back end, you can do this very easily using folders in assets. So that is not strictly a category, but might fill the purpose.

For the front end it's super fast as well. You can insert a complete folder in a field in one go.

The only thing might be that it will not automatically update files that are added in the back end, you would need to add these in the field.

PS; you can order the items at will, by dragging them around in the field.